# Is one more correct: "lucky for me" or "luckily for me"?

Tags: word-choice, grammaticality, adjectives, adverbs

Is it "more" correct to say "Luckily for me" or "Lucky for me"? I found a few sites that discussed this (including m-w.com, under the rubric "hopefully") but I'm still not sure if one is specifically right or wrong, or both are acceptable. (Or one is right, while the other is acceptable using colloquial language.)

Comment: *Lucky for me* is usually just short for *it was lucky for me.*

Answer (score 7):

Both are correct.  *Lucky for me* is simply shortened, which is grammatically fine.

*Lucky for me* is an elliptic form of *It was lucky for me*.  E.g:

> *[It was] lucky for me [that] I saw the sniper before he saw me.*

*Luckily for me* is a complete adverbial phrase, and not truncated:

> *Luckily for me, I saw the sniper before he saw me.*

*Lucky for me* seems to have become more popular than *Luckily for me* since about 1980, according to [Ngrams](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=Lucky+for+me%2CLuckily+for+me&case_insensitive=on&year_start=1950&year_end=2008&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t4%3B%2CLucky%20for%20me%3B%2Cc0%3B%2Cs0%3B%3BLucky%20for%20me%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Blucky%20for%20me%3B%2Cc0%3B.t4%3B%2CLuckily%20for%20me%3B%2Cc0%3B%2Cs0%3B%3BLuckily%20for%20me%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Bluckily%20for%20me%3B%2Cc0):

[image]

Comment: This is incorrect. If you look at the frequency for the period 1990-2010 they are about the same http://ngrams.googlelabs.com/graph?content=Lucky+for+me%2CLuckily+for+me&year_start=1990&year_end=2010&corpus=0&smoothing=3

Comment: As a general rule, if you want to study the present usage, I advise you to set the Ngrams from last decades, not from 1800

Answer (score 1):

Luckily, as it's an adverb. Compare it to 'happily'. You wouldn't say:

> Happy for me, I met my long-lost brother the other day.

Comment: But you would say "he is happy for me".  And you would say "that is lucky for me".  So it really just depends on the syntactic context, rather than a rule for all situations.

Comment: I didn't say it was a rule, I just said that, given the choice of the two examples, 'luckily' was the correct one.

Comment: @ElendilTheTall: That's fine — except with no context given, it is impossible to tell which one is correct.

Comment: The context is implied by the choice, I think, i.e. when do you use luckily. I realise you could read it either way, but I am just intuitively incisive like that ;)

Comment: The key is, at least to make it proper, to use the non-adverbial form, you have to add "it is", which makes it an adjective. "Luckily" is the correct form.